# How to find all tables where trigger does not exist

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

The other day we found a table that had a `ModifiedDate` column but discovered there was no trigger in place to actually update that column. Now I'm trying to write a script to find all of the tables that have a `ModifiedDate` column but no trigger to update it.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
SELECT so.name AS 'TableName', sc.name AS 'ColumnName', tr.name AS 'Trigger'
FROM sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.object_id = so.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.triggers tr ON so.object_id=tr.object_id
WHERE so.type = 'U' AND sc.name LIKE '%ModifiedDate%' 
AND tr.type = 'TR'
```

To start, I want to find all of the tables that have both the column and trigger. I'm able to find all of the tables with the `ModifiedDate` column but when I add in that last where filter `AND tr.type = 'TR'` it returns nothing. I checked and there are tables in there that have both the column and trigger I'm looking for so I would expect to see those on the list.

Comment: Your use of `WHERE` converts the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You must either allow for `NULL` values or move the appropriate conditions to the `ON` clauses.

Comment: @HABO And the fact he's joining on the WRONG column...? His query, with the correct column name (parent_id) performs what he needs. "To start, I want to find all of the tables that have both the column and trigger."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT so.name AS 'TableName', sc.name AS 'ColumnName', tr.name AS 'Trigger'
FROM sys.objects so
INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON sc.object_id = so.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.triggers tr ON so.object_id=tr.parent_id
WHERE so.type = 'U' AND sc.name LIKE '%ModifiedDate%' 
AND tr.type = 'TR'
```

Your join was wrong on Triggers

Cleaning up your query, to find all tables where there are NO triggers where they perhaps should be:

```
Select  t.name As 'TableName'
       ,c.name As 'ColumnName'
       ,tr.name As 'Trigger'
From    sys.tables t
Join    sys.columns c On c.object_id = t.object_id
Left Join sys.triggers tr On t.object_id = tr.parent_id
Where   c.name Like '%ModifiedDate%'
        And tr.name Is Null
```

I took out some superfluous stuff. Selecting against tables removes the need to look for Type = 'U' and the parent_id\object_id relationship is such that you don't need to also enforce it with the Type = 'TR' clause.

Comment: object_id on sys.triggers is the object for the trigger. To find the table a trigger is attached to you need parent_id

Comment: I tried this query but am only getting back results for one table. It seems like the left join isn't working?

Comment: The query does exactly what you requested. Pulls back values for all tables with triggers where the table has a column called ModifiedDate. I just tested it out and got one row the first time, two after I added a second table with a corresponding column name and trigger. You join logic is funky and it won't work for the next step, however my answer fulfills exactly what was asked for.

Comment: Every test I ran came back with the expected results. Have you verified that the column names etc. are correct on your side?

Comment: Thank you for your help! The second query you listed worked for me.